# Add icons to semantic-ui namespace

Tags: font-awesome, semantic-ui

SUI includes Fontawesome iconset, but I need to add more icons.
E.g. I'd like to add a chopper icon and use `chopper` class on `i` tag.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look around https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/ since it's based on Font Awesome, you might find how the current icons are specified and make your own.